# How do I create an empty project in Xcode 6 for watchKit?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am working first time on `watchkit` where when i am adding target as `apple watchkit` it creates an target for `apple watch`with `storyboard` but i want to create an empty project for `watchkit` where i can add my `xibs` So if anybody knows please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: during project creation after you named it and have selected template (Watchkit in your case) uncheck story board option.

Comment: will you please give some detailed explanation I don't understand and Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically you can not add xib for iWatch app. It only allows you to add storyboard by default. Try to add new file to Watchkit/iWatch project it generally shows like this in xcode,
[image: Xcode adding a file to iwatch app extension]

So in any case you have to use storyboard for iwatch watchkit app.